My mesh is broken, why is this? It is not a orientation issue


I began my blender journey 2 months ago, I was planning to do a figure but this happened, ruined my whole model. This shading is not working even I shade it flat.

Try Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Thx, its solved, very appreciate you!

It is because of messed up split normals (the normals that determine the shading), go intô Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data.
